# While creating session factory object using spring it is showing error"

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException. Below is my XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<!-- Add support for component scanning -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.code.springdemo" />

<!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
<bean
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
<bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
    <property name="user" value="springstudent" />
    <property name="password" value="springstudent" /> 

    <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
</bean>  
<!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.code.springdemo.entity" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
          <prop 
    key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
       </props>
    </property>
```

```
<!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
 <bean id="myTransactionManager"
     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />
```

Comment: Let me guess using Java 9 or 10 and didn't include Jaxb as a dependency.

Comment: @M.Deinum how to include jaxb without using maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer :

Use --add-modules to add module in classpath.

As Java has not yet removed from module from java 9. Java has only deprecated and does not add javax.xml.bind module on classpath by default.

So if we want to add javax.xml.bind on classpath we can add using following command.

--add-modules java.xml.bind

RUN AS->RUN Configuration->Arguments (In Eclipse)